# StringFormat Currency special formatting

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, string-formatting

I'm trying to do a special formatting for currency in my XAML.
This is the format I want in the UI : 123 456 789,12 €.
So the 'scpace' char for group separator and the ',' char for decimal separator.

Does anyone know how to proceed ?
Or does anyone got an interesting link which explain how to construct StringFormat in XAML ?

EDIT : Or simply put the French Culture for the UI :-)

Cheers,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your input is but here's an example on how to format currencies depending on the culture.

```
  Decimal amount= 12356789.12M;
  String s = amount.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
  // s =     "12 356 789,12 €"
```

Comment: Yes I know that but I wanted to do this in XAML.

But I get it :

    Binding="{Binding Path=TechnicalCostAmount, StringFormat=C0, ConverterCulture=fr-FR}"

Cheers

Thomas